# Windows 10 on Ryzen 1700x starts processes slowly

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, process, amd-ryzen

I have Windows 10 (22H2, 10.0.19045) installed on the following system:

- Ryzen 1700x
- 32 GB of RAM
- 1 TB Samsung 970 EVO (M.2)
- Windows Defender virus scanner.

About 2 months ago, the system started behaving weirdly when starting new processes. Sometimes, the processes take several seconds to start.

An example situation is when many tabs (~50) are opened in Chrome all at the same time.

Before the issue occurred, all 50 tabs would start loading at the same time. Now, they load one-after-another with at most 2 or 3 loading in parallel. Additionally, when I try to open the task manager or any other new process (like Wordpad), their start is also delayed by several seconds.

When I try to shut down (or suspend) the system in that case, the shut down also takes > 10 seconds to begin shutting down the PC.

Neither the CPU nor the disk is used very much when that happens. And once loaded, the processes (like the Chrome tabs) run quickly and without any hiccups. Videos running in the background (VLC or YouTube) keep running smoothly.

Once the processes start, the performance of the PC is not impacted. Games still run at their old speed, disk and network I/O is as fast as always.

I have already tried:

- disabling the virus scanner
- trying different browsers
- altering/disabling the virtual memory settings
- update all relevant system and graphics drivers.

Nothing helped solve this issue.

Note that when I boot a Ubuntu instance from a USB stick, no such issue occurs on that OS.

Does anybody have an idea what it might be? What could've changed in the last few months?

Comment: Check the SMART attributes of the disk. If you don't have such a product use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy). If any storage attribute is not marked as "Good", let us know. Check also the Event Viewer for useful messages.

Comment: The SMART attributes are okay. No critical warnings and enough available spare (0x64).

Only the temperature is a bit on the higher side, with 65°C, which isn't too surprising given how close the M.2 slot is to the CPU.

Comment: Also, the Windows Event Viewer lists nothing extraordinary, as far as I can see. After all, everything works, it's just small delays for processes to start.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode ?

Comment: Interesting. In safe mode it does not occur and processes start normally. Now, when I rebooted into normal mode again, it also seems to work in normal mode again.

I will observe what happens the next few days and post if it changes back to the bad behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, after another reboot, the issue returned. It does only seem to happen if a large number of processes (like tabs in Chrome) are started at the same time. When it's only a few new tabs/processes, the delay is not really noticeable.

Comment: Try to test this when booting in Safe mode with Network ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)). If it doesn't happen in this mode, then some installed product is responsible for this problem.

Comment: I did the earlier test on safe mode with network drivers on. I am unsure though which installed software or driver could cause this behaviour, since it affects nothing except when many processes are started in a short amount of time. That is why I suspected the Windows virus scanner, but disabling it changed nothing. I'll continue to check out what app or dirver could've caused it, but I would appreciate any further ideas.

Comment: [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) can help with speedily disabling/enabling bunches of startup programs.